# Error pferror.cpp536pfhandleunsupportedexception on PowerBi, what is?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following error in my PowerBI project:
pferror.cpp536PFHandleUnsupportedException, more be more precise pferror.cpp536PFHandleUnsupportedException::::operator()

I have no idea of what causes it or even what it means, as I couldn't find anything on Google.

What I am trying to do:

- I have 3 tables A, B and C that I want to get data from, all of them have a foreing key that links them to an user(userID).
- The tables are linked as following: A <--> B and A <--> C. B and C cannot be linked as B may not have entries for a given userID.

What I have investigated:

- Removing the table C from the source data somehow fixes the error, but I do not know why;
- Table C SQL query runs fine on Microsoft SQL Server Manager Studio;
- Removing table A and/or B, does not solve the problem, so I think the table C is the one causing the issue.
- Attempting to get data only from table C is painfully slow(over 5 minutes), but it gets done withou error.

From this, I think the problem is related to the table C, but I don't know exactly what causes it.
Note: table C is a view of a table with over a 10 millions rows.